# Problem with adding rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem adding rows to the table with this code and I can't solve it.

```js
function add() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!checkEmptyInput()) {
      var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
        cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
        cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
        cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
        cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3),
        cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4),
        product = document.getElementById("ins-product").value,
        color = document.getElementById("ins-color").value,
        price = document.getElementById("ins-price").value;
        
      cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="select">';
      cell2.innerHTML = product;
      cell3.innerHTML = color;
      cell4.innerHTML = price;
      cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="edit" id="edit">';
      //selectedRowToInput();
    }
    
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
  });
  
  clearinput();
}

function remove() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var index = 1;

  while (index < table.rows.length) {
    var input = table.rows[index].cells[0].children[0];

    if (input && input.checked) {
      table.deleteRow(index);
    } else {
      index++;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
    <table id="table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select"></td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select"></td>
        <td>A3</td>
        <td>B3</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="select" class="select"></td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button onclick="add();">Add</button>
  <button onclick="remove();">Remove</button>
  <div class="popup" id="popup">
    First Name :<input type="text" name="Product" id="ins-product"> Last Name :<input type="text" name="Color" id="ins-color"> Age :<input type="number" name="Price" id="ins-price">
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    <!--button onclick="edit();">Edit</button>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use add for the second time it adds two rows at once. And for the third time, it adds three rows of the same value. The number of rows inserting increases when I click on add repeatedly.

Comment: Everytime you call the add function you also add the click handler again. Previous attached handler don't get removed, so you now the code is adding two rows. If you call the add function again it will add a third time, resulting in 3 rows added. And so on.

Comment: On a "modern html + js" note, don't put any JS in your HTML. No `<button onclick="something()">`, keep the HTML clean, and on the JS side find your element and then only use `thatElement.addEventListener("click", ...)`. If you read your code, you'll notice you're actually doing _both_ now, and that can't possibly be what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Got Some Undefined Functions and miss Placing functions Causing The issue.

The General Rule For Adding A New Row To the Table Is :

```
// Insert a row in the table at the last row
var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow();

// Insert a cell in the row at index 0
var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
```

For Your Specific "code"

 The Event Listener For The Button With id = "add"

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",function(){
```

Must Be Outside the function add to be triggered probably
Another Error Will Appear As the function "checkEmptyInput()" is no defined
Simply define or remove it for your code to work.

Here's a working code for you:

```
    <script>

        document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",function(){
                            if(!checkEmptyInput()){
                                var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
                                    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
                                    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
                                    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
                                    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3),
                                    cell5 = newRow.insertCell(4),
                                    product = document.getElementById("ins-product").value,
                                    color = document.getElementById("ins-color").value,
                                    price = document.getElementById("ins-price").value;
                                cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="select">';
                                cell2.innerHTML = product;
                                cell3.innerHTML = color;
                                cell4.innerHTML = price;
                                cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="edit" id="edit">';
                                //selectedRowToInput();
                            }
                            document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";        
                        });

        function add()
                    {
                        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";

                    }

        function remove () {

                        var table = document.getElementById("table"); 

                        var index = 1;

                        while (index < table.rows.length) {
                          var input = table.rows[index].cells[0].children[0];

                          if (input && input.checked) {
                            table.deleteRow(index);
                          }
                          else {
                            index++;
                          }
                        }
                      }

    </script>
```